# Type mismatch in nested contravariant type

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, contravariance

Given such class (part of it)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class A {
    private Map<String, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Collection<String>> getMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<Map.Entry<? super K, ? super V>> comparator) {
        return map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(comparator)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }

    public Map<String, Collection<String>> getSortedMap() {
        Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>> cmp =
                Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Collection::size));
        return sorted(getMap(), cmp);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on compile

```
error: method sorted in class A cannot be applied to given types;
    return sorted(getMap(), cmp);
            ^
            required: Map<K,V>,Comparator<Entry<? super K,? super V>>
        found: Map<String,Collection<String>>,Comparator<Entry<String,Collection<String>>>
        reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) K,V
        (argument mismatch; Comparator<Entry<String,Collection<String>>> cannot be converted to Comparator<Entry<? super K,? super V>>)
        where K,V are type-variables:
        K extends Object declared in method <K,V>sorted(Map<K,V>,Comparator<Entry<? super K,? super V>>)
        V extends Object declared in method <K,V>sorted(Map<K,V>,Comparator<Entry<? super K,? super V>>)
        1 error
```

When I change `A.sorted` signature to be invariant over `comparator` parameter i.e. `<K, V> Map<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> comparator)` it compiles without any issues. However, I don't think my code violates any typing relations. Is this a problem with Java's type inference?

I am using OpenJDK 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are invariant. If you declare a parameter `Comparater<T>` then it expects exactly `Comparator<T>`. In this case case you have `K` and `V` trough the map which makes `K = String` and `V = Collection<String>`. That would make the second parameter `Comparator<Entry<? super String, ? super Collection<String>>>`, and you can not assign a `Comparator<Entry<String,Collection<String>>>` to that, since the type argument to the comparator does not *exactly* match.

You could declare the `Comparator` contra-variant instead:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map,
        Comparator<? super Map.Entry<K, V>> comparator) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Mmhm, I kind of see the problem now. I do agree about inferred types for `K` and `V` (that's what I wanted anyway), but I don't understand variance bit here. Looks like `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>>` really isn't subtype of `Comparator<Map.Entry<? super String, ? super Collection<String>>>`, but why? `String` is supertype of `String`, and so is `Collection<String>` to `Collection<String>`.

Comment: Well, `Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>>` is certainly a subtype of `Map.Entry<? super String, ? super Collection<String>>` but the subtype relationship breaks when you build `Comparator`s for each of those types because something that can compare two `Map.Entry<String,Collection<String>>` objects can't necessarily compare two arbitrary `Map.Entry<? super String, ? super Collection<String>>` objects.

Comment: @DavidWallace, thanks! Now I do understand this. I will stick to `<K, V> Map<K, V> sorted(Map<K, V> map, Comparator<? super Map.Entry<K, V>> comparator)` then. :)